# (Dark Mode) How do I get the background to change after the "dark-theme" is added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

so I have a button on my website that is supposed to toggle dark mode. I see in my inspection that the toggle is working but for some reason, the #content .dark-theme isn't being seen. I thought that the child took precedence.

HTML

```
<!-- Main Content -->
  <div id="content">
```

CSS

```
    #content {
    background: rgb(248, 201, 201);
    color: black;
}

#content .dark-theme {
    background: rgb(49, 51, 71);
    color: white;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('change-theme-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
content.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
```

});

Comment: try `#content.dark-theme` instead of `#content .dark-theme`... notice the space between selectors

Comment: Should be `#content.dark-theme`

Comment: That worked! I didn't realize there was a difference. I see people use spaces in between parent and child so I'm still a bit confused but I can look that up. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ok thanks, everybody. When I wrote my answer there was only 1 comment so I thought I had to write it but then once I wrote it, there were answers. Also, I'm not sure if "Answered" should be the best answer or the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `#content.dark-theme` to correctly target the element you need; here you can see this in action.

In CSS, when you write: `#content .dark-theme` you are trying to target the element with a class `dark-theme` that is a child of an element with an id `content`.

In your case, what you want to target is the element `#content` itself; so you should write: `#content.dark-theme` or just `#content`; with this you are targeting the element `#content` that ALSO has a class `dark-theme`

```js
document.getElementById('change-theme-btn').onclick = function() {
  content.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
}
```

```css
#content {
  background: rgb(248, 201, 201);
  color: black;
  height: 150px;
}

#content.dark-theme {
  background: rgb(49, 51, 71);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  This is content
</div>
<button id="change-theme-btn">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove #content before .dark-theme in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
#content .dark-theme {
    background: rgb(49, 51, 71);
    color: white;
}
```

to

```
#content.dark-theme {
    background: rgb(49, 51, 71);
    color: white;
}
```

Reason: Having the space, means: An item with class 'dark-theme' which is a CHILDREN of an item with Id "content".  Without the space, it becomes "An item which has Id content AND class dark-theme".